# New branch from gitlab won't appear in git bash

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, git-bash

I created a new branch using Gitlab GUI. I opened up my git bash and ran git branch, but the newly created branch won't appear there. How do I push my latest commit to the newly created branch now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Force to pull the latest:

`git fetch origin`

If you create one named  recentUIbranch on the UI, you will see:

`* [new branch]      <recentUIbranch>        -> origin/<recentUIbranch>`

Jump into the branch:
`git checkout -b <recentUIbranch>`

You can now do some changes on that branch.

When you push:
`git push --set-upstream origin <recentUIbranch>`